# Web Essentials 2012 - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I cannot see the typescript option in VS2012, as I need to change target to EcmaScript 5 I also cannot see the split screen.
I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it but I still cannot see it, any ideas?

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript support was removed in web essentials 3.x the visual studio will now come with built in typescript support. Currently there are a bunch of features pending, split views are one of them.

Comment: What needs to de done in this case? I am using web essential 2.8 and typescript 0.9.5. I am getting "The TypeScript compiler couldn't be found." error while saving typescript file.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite update your web essentials and let visual studio save your file for you

Answer (score 0):

VS 2012, TypeScript 0.9.1.1, Web Essentials 2012 v2.7 ---

Navigate to...

Menu 'TOOLS' -> 'Options...' -> 'Web Essentials' -> 'TypeScript'
evaluate property 'Show preview window'.  If True I get split screen, if false I do not.

If you need to install TypeScript independent of Web Essentials, see....

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

See SO Article...

[Old version of TypeScript installation program (.MSI, or .VSIX) needed - 0.9.1.1 - where to find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412486/old-version-of-typescript-installation-program-msi-or-vsix-needed-0-9-1-1)