# Right side panel of TypeScript files doesn't update properly

Tags: typescript

I've just installed TypeScript 0.9.5 on my Visual Studio 2012. For some files everything is OK. But for some files or even same files at different times, the following error shows in the right side panel of `ts` files.

```
/*

Compile Error. 
See error list for details
 The TypeScript compiler couldn't be found. Download http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download

*/
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339659/390330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use WebEssentials with TypeScript 0.9.5

WebEssentials no longer supports typescript.

Comment: You mean that I totally uninstall it? Or there's a way to just disable it on TypeScript files?