# The TypeScript compiler couldn't be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and TypeScript version 0.9.5. I am also using web essentials 2.8. After I try to save the TypeScript file, it says:

1. **Compile Error.**
2. **See error list for details**
3. **The TypeScript compiler couldn't be found. Download http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download**

But even downloading  latest version did not help. I checked some links but could not find the solution.

[Right side panel of TypeScript files doesn't update properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947216/right-side-panel-of-typescript-files-doesnt-update-properly)

[Cannot compile TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051515/cannot-compile-typescript-files-in-visual-studio-2012)

Please help.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a really old version of web essentials with a new version of TypeScript. WebEssentials reduced its typescript support after v3.x so as to not conflict with Visual Studio tooling for TypeScript.

You can get the latest WebEssentials here : http://vswebessentials.com/download

Comment: After updating the web essentials, when I save the TS file, system is not generating the latest JS file. I looked at Tools > Options > Web Essentials > type Script in VS 2012, earlier there use to be lot of options (One of which was to generate JS file when you save TS file) but now I only see one option and that option is Show Preview Window. What happened to all those options? How can I enable JS file generation when I save TS file ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also had the error message "The typescript compiler couldn't be found". 
I had an older version of Web Essentials and when I installed version 3.7 the error message dissapeared but no js files where created. 
Then in: Tools->Options->Text Editor->Typescript->Project 
I checked "Compile on Save" (Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project) and then the js file got compiled.

Also when I look at the properties of the typescript file I now see TypeScriptCompile in Build Action. When I had the older version of Web Essentials I did not have the option "TypeScriptCompile" in Build Action.