# Old version of TypeScript installation program (.MSI, or .VSIX) needed - 0.9.1.1 - where to find?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

Anybody know how to get the .MSI installer for an older version of Typescript - the download at the offical URL for [version 0.9.1.1](https://typescript.codeplex.com/releases/view/111080) is no longer available.

It seems newer [version 1.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa041d2d-5d77-494b-b0ba-8b4550792b4d) or [1.0.1.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac357f1e-9847-46ac-a4cf-520325beaec1) is available, but that version is incompatible with my client's software which I am attempting to support.

Any idea how to get the specific version I need?

Comment: Maybe version 0.9.1.1 doesn't have a .MSI or .VSIX?  Well, if the binaries are available in a different way, I'll take it...  I just don't want to have to compile the tool.  If I need to compile it from source, I will need to install nodejs so I can compile Jake, so I can compile Typescript....  Too much for what should be a download...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - found it.  After some digging, there is a reference in the [bowels of the Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) for many old versions of TypeScript.

Expand the 'Details' section and scroll down, click 'Download' link on desired version...

[image: MS Download Center showing old versions of TypeScript]